# How Bugzilla will be working on local PC?

Tags: bugzilla

I've installed bugzilla version 3.6.3 on my local system. When i click on "Open a new account" button/link and after entering my valid email i got following error.

**"There was an error sending mail from 'bugzilla-daemon@' to 'myemailaddress@example.com':Couldn't connect to mail"**

can anybody help me how to create an user account on local PC ?

Operating system is Win 7. I want to create 1 admin account, some user accounts and through Admin I want to give them limited or full access. I also want to see the database tables, modify them, create new tables etc.

is it possible on local PC ? or what should i need to do to make it possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't a mail server running on your local machine. Exactly what you want to do depends partly on what oerating system you machine is running

Comment: @ColinFine: Thank you so much for your comment. Operating system is Win 7. I want to create 1 admin account and some user accounts and through Admin I want to give them limited or full access. I also want to see the database tables, modify them, create new tables etc. 

is it possible on local PC ? or what should i need to do to make it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done now. There is some installation setting where i was making mistake.

Well, there are 4 kinds accounts with passwords required field.

1. root
2. bugs
3. admin (you will use it to get login)
4. Windows Username and password.

My mistake was that, I had not given windows username and password at fourth level. But now it works fine when i install it again and given windows username and password.

Answer (score 0):

I landed here looking for bugzilla's setup for email-less service (let's say you want to run your own bugzilla in a local server without sending emails etc.). I am following the directions for linux in [here](http://vibhurishi.blogspot.com/2009/05/howto-install-bugzilla-on-ubuntu-9.html). Thereafter, to get this to work in machines without email support (or for some reason you don't want bugzilla sending emails--maybe this bug db is private), you do the following:

```
$ ./checksetup.pl --make-admin=silly@sillydomain.com
$ ./checksetup.pl --reset-password=silly@sillydomain.com
```

Then, open up `data/params` and edit the line that says `mail_delivery_method` to `Test` instead of `SendMail`. Run `./checksetup.pl` again just in case (is this needed? not entirely sure).

Then, using a browser, go to the URL http:///bugzilla, and login using the username silly@sillydomain.com and the password you set in the second step above, you should be able to login and set up the product/component names, create bugs, create accounts etc.