# How to setup Bugzilla without SMTP server (no need to use e-mails)?

Tags: bugzilla

How to setup Bugzilla without SMTP server (no need to use e-mails) ?

I installed `Bugzilla` from the windows-installer. We just use it locally and don't need emails, nor we have any `SMTP` server.

[This link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mozilla.support.bugzilla/hrH-owndUVU) says that I don't have to have SMTP, but I don't know how to get to the "Administrator page"

Comment: Please see my response in [this SO post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013958/how-bugzilla-will-be-working-on-local-pc/25588725#25588725

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One needs to set the 'mail_delivery_method' parameter to 'Test'. Check for the new account creation mails in C:\bugzilla\data folder mailer.testfile file and you will get the token link there to actually create the new user. This way you can really bypass setting up a SMTP server totally but to use Bugzilla within a group of ppl. Very useful for small group developments and bug tracking.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the 'mail_delivery_method' parameter to None to disable sending email. Login as a Bugzilla administrator to get to the Administration page, then select Parameters then Email.